# Smack API ,ChatMessageListener interface not working properly

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am a beginner in smack api , and I have already wasted 1 day experimenting with it and understanding it .Please be kind

the below method is not getting invoked :

```
@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    Log.d("processMessage234:", "Getting Message here");

}
```

below is my full java code:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements ChatManagerListener,ChatMessageListener,PacketListener {

MyXmpp2 myXmpp2;
Button isOnline;
AbstractXMPPConnection connection;
ChatManager chatManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    isOnline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    myXmpp2 = new MyXmpp2();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    isOnline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            connection = myXmpp2.getConnection();
            Log.d("isOnline:", myXmpp2.getConnection().isConnected() + "");

            chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            Chat c = chatManager.createChat("baba@abc", new ChatMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    Log.d("processMessage000:", "Getting Message here");
                }
            });

            try {
                c.sendMessage("lol");
                //This is working fine
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {

    if (!createdLocally) {
        chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                Log.d("processMessage:", "Getting Message here");
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    Log.d("processMessage234:", "Getting Message here");
//This is not getting invoked

}

@Override
public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
    Log.d("processPacket:", "Getting Packets here");
}
```

}

I can read in the log the packets packets sent and packets received as below:

```
D/SMACK: SENT (0): <message to='baba@abc ......
D/SMACK: SENT (0): <message from='baba@abc ......
```

But i am unable to invoke the method

```
void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message){.....  }
```

Any Suggestion is very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Mack94 for saving my day, I am uploading my full code to help others

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

MyXmpp2 myXmpp2;
Button isOnline;
AbstractXMPPConnection connection;
ChatManager chatManager;
ChatManagerListener chatManagerListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    isOnline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    myXmpp2 = new MyXmpp2();



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    isOnline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            connection = myXmpp2.getConnection();
            Log.d("isOnline:", myXmpp2.getConnection().isConnected() + "");


            chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);


    });

    chatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {

            chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    Log.d("Hello::","World");
                    if(message.getBody()!=null)
                    {
                        Log.d("Message::",message.getBody());

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    Log.d("processMessage234:", "Getting Message here");

}
```

I don't understand well what are you trying to do but it isn't invoked because it need to be invoked in `ChatMessageListener`. It need to work on different thread than the whole app, due to `constant listening`.

Here you are running new thread, so it should work and should listening to the incoming messages.

```
chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        Log.d("processMessage:", "Getting Message here");
    }
});
```

Please explain more, I will try to help!

Comment: The answer is wrong. OP's `Activity` extends `ChastMessageListener`. Furthermore, the callback is always invoked in a different thread from the Activity's (which would be the UI/main thread).

Comment: Where my answer is wrong? It's absolutly right. I don't make a mistake anywhere. What's more, where `Avtivity` extends `ChatMessageListender`? I dont see.

Comment: First of all, thanks to both of you for helping me out . I am just going to try your code Mack and one more thing `ChastMessageListener` is an interface.Why are you saying Activity extends `ChastMessageListener`?

Comment: Because you wrote "public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements ChatManagerListener,ChatMessageListener,PacketListener"